# Finding the cross section of a couple of surfaces

Tags: geometry

$$x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=4$$
$$x^{2}+y^{2}=1$$
$$x=0$$
$$y=0$$
$$y^{2}+z^{2}=4$$

How should I do this? I thought of, taking surfaces from the last one:

1. $y^{2}+z^{2}=4$ is a circle drew on the ZY plane, and now that we have no x in the formula, it creates an infinite cylidner parallel to the OX.
2. $y=0$ is a "wall" placed on the OX
3. $x=0$ is a "wall" placed on the OY
4. $x^{2}+y^{2}=1$ is a cylinder
5. $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=4$ is a sphere

However, the internet course says that the first and the last surfaces are the same - a sphere...But how's that possible? Where do I make a mistake? And what will the cross section be?

Answer (score 0):

They might be referring to the concept of a sphere in two dimensions, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere.

As for the "cross-section" (assuming you mean intersection of all surfaces), look closely at equations 2-4 and see if there is any problem...